# Need some clear explainations about the importance of anchor box in yolov3

Tags: python, yolo

I'm trying to understand YOLOv3's algorithm. I've watched Andrew Ng's video on Coursera about uses of anchor box in object detection model, especially in YOLOv3. But I still don't understand some points:
- If I try to change the value of my face detection model's anchor boxes, it leads to very poor results. What is the importance of anchor box in class predicting YOLO?
- YOLOv3 uses only 9 anchor boxes, 3 for each scale for default. So if we have to detect an object from 80 classes, and each class has a different usual shape, what does the shape of these anchor boxes look like?
I'm new to computer vision and machine learning, so my questions could be hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the Anchor box is to detect multiple objects of different sizes for which the center is located in the same cell. Changing the number of anchor boxes leads to a change in length of ground truth and prediction array.

Assuming a single box(in a cell) has following predictions for 80 classes [Pc,P1,P2...P80,X1,Y1,X2,Y2] i.e 85, then 9 anchor boxes will have 85*9 = 765 length array predictions.

Below is an example of anchor boxes plotted around (0,0) of different scales.

[image: Anchor Boxes around (0,0)]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I have 1 more question? I'm not clearly understand why YOLO can but not calculate directly the dimension of the bouding box instead of the offset value for these anchors?

Comment: I think this article explains this even though it is for Faster RCNN. https://tryolabs.com/blog/2018/01/18/faster-r-cnn-down-the-rabbit-hole-of-modern-object-detection/

Comment: Thank for sharing !

Comment: @DoriHp0 Joseph Redmon explained in one of his papers that he tried a version of YOLO where the output predicted the width and height of bounding boxes directly, instead of using anchors, and it wasn't as good. Also, I think the big difference between YOLOv1 and YOLOv2 was the addition of anchors. You might want to check out CornerNet and CenterNet which seem to achieve better results than YOLOv3 without using anchors.